# ODBC change json array format

Tags: php, sql, json, odbc

I'm getting sql data using a ms access odbc. However I'm not getting the results in the format I would like. Here is my code:

```
$rs = odbc_exec($con, $sql);
if (!$rs) {
    exit("There is an error in the SQL!");
}
$data[0] = array('D','CPU_Purchased_ghz');
$i = 1;

while($row = odbc_fetch_array($rs)) {
    $data[$i] = $row;
    $i++;
}

odbc_close($con); // Closes the connection
$json = json_encode($data); // Generates the JSON, saves it in a variable
echo $json;
```

The way I'm getting results is in the format:

```
[
    ["D","CPU_Purchased_ghz"],
    {"D":"2015-03-14 00:00:00","CPU_Purchased_ghz":"10.00"},
    {"D":"2015-03-15 00:00:00","CPU_Purchased_ghz":"10.00"},
    {"D":"2015-03-16 00:00:00","CPU_Purchased_ghz":"10.00"}
];
```

I want it to look like this:

```
[
    ["D","CPU_Purchased_ghz"],
    [""2015-03-14 00:00:00",10.00],
    ["2015-03-16 00:00:00",10.00]
]
```

Any idea how to fix this/alter my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
while($row = odbc_fetch_array($rs)) {
    $data[$i] = array(
        $row['D'],
        $row['CPU_Purchased_ghz']
    );
    $i++; 
}
```

Comment: If this solved your problem can you please accept it as the answer? Thanks.